# Send multiple field arrays via ajax to Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I need help with saving a drag n drop menu order. I use http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable to drag and update the list. Each menu item has two hidden fields: `id` and `order`. The order is updated dynamically when dropped. I don't know how to turn the fields `id` and `order` into a correct array so I can update via AJAX into Laravel.

HTML - Menu :

```
<div>
    <input name="menu[1][id]" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input name="menu[1][order]" class="new-order" type="hidden" value="3">
</div>
<div>
    <input name="menu[2][id]" type="hidden" value="2">
    <input name="menu[2][order]" class="new-order" type="hidden" value="4">
</div>
<div>
    <input name="menu[3][id]" type="hidden" value="3">
    <input name="menu[3][order]" class="new-order" type="hidden" value="5">
</div>
```

jQuery - Drag/drop, update order value then send via ajax :

```
// Sortable options
$('.nav-pages__items').sortable({
    handle: '.nav-pages__drag',
    items: ':not(.home)'
}).bind('sortupdate', function() {

    // When dropped clear list order
    $(this).find('input[name=menu]').attr('value', '');
    // Then update list order
    $('.nav-pages__items li:not(.home)').each(function(i, element) {
        element = i+1;
        $(this).find('input.new-order').attr('value'),
            $(this).find('input.new-order').attr('value', + element);
    });

    // !! Somehow create array to send/save !!

    // Ajax to send
    $.post('/menu-update', {
        _token: token,
        id: id,
        order: order
    }, function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'success') {
            console.log('success: ', data);
        } else if (data.error == 'error') {
            console.log('error: ', data);
        };
    });

});
```

PHP/Laravel - Not got this far (without errors):

```
public function update()
{
    $menu = Input::all();

    $save = Page::where('id', $menu['id'])->update([
        'order' => $menu['order']
    ]);

    if ($save) {
        $response = [
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'Message here',
            'id' => $menu['id'],
            'order' => $menu['order'],
        ];
    };

    return Response::json($response);
}
```

To summarise:

1. Get the `id` and `order` for each field group
2. Loop though them in js and crate correct array
3. Send array to Laravel and update `order` based on `id`

Also, if there's a much simpler way to do this, I'm all ears.

Comment: Can you explain this line of code: 
 `$(this).find('input.new-order').attr('value'),
            $(this).find('input.new-order').attr('value', + element);`
 It looks to me like that first `find()` isn't doing anything -- am I crazy?

Comment: I hadn't updated the field name. It's clearing the list order and starting it again (1, 2, 3, desc)

Comment: Can you tell me what `$(this).find('input.new-order').attr('value')` returns in your sortable function? I can't create the final order array without knowing that.

Comment: What is `input.new-order` ? Can you show the HTML for that element?

Comment: I'm not seeing the necessity of all of those hidden id and order elements -- I think this can be done using only the inputs that they're dragging and dropping, but I can't submit this an an answer without knowing more about those inputs.

Comment: I've updated the question - The class 'new-order' is so js can update the new order once dropped (it clears the order then re-enters it desc.). Hope that helps

Comment: The numbers in name="menu[2][order]" is the id of the menu item

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85332/discussion-between-ben-and-jack-barham).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you need those hidden inputs -- what about something like:

jQuery:

```
// Sortable options
$('.nav-pages__items').sortable({
    handle: '.nav-pages__drag',
    items: ':not(.home)'
}).bind('sortupdate', function() {

    // Collect the new orderings
    var newOrders = [];
    $('.nav-pages__items li:not(.home)').each(function(i, element) {
        var id = $(element).data('id'); // Set a data-id attribute on each li
        var order = i;
        newOrders[order] = id;
    });

    // Ajax to send
    $.post('/menu-update', {
        _token: token,
        newOrders: newOrders
    }, function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'success') {
            console.log('success: ', data);
        } else if (data.error == 'error') {
            console.log('error: ', data);
        };
    });

});
```

PHP/Laravel:

```
public function update()
{
    $responses = [];
    foreach (Input::get('newOrders') AS $order => $id) {
        $save = Page::where('id', $id)->update([
            'order' => $order
        ]);

        if ($save) {
            $response[$id] = [
                'status' => 'success',
                'msg' => 'Message here',
                'id' => $id,
                'order' => $order,
            ];
        }

    }


    return Response::json($responses);
}
```

Comment: Just heading home now - I'll check when I get back :)

Comment: The above gives me a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined` error on `newOrders[order] = id;` - However I've slightly adjusted it and posted the answer below. But as it's all based on the above I'm going to answer this as correct and post my version below :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to initialize the array. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Ahhhh, that might be the issue I had. I'll check when back at my desk.

Comment: Had to swap `$id => $order` to $order => $id` and it's worked perfectly :)

Comment: Thank you so much again for your help :)